# Dictionary with user details

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I want to create a dictionary with name, age, sex, location. After creating I add the dictionary to array and pass to other function. I could not figure out how to store multiple attributes in a dictionary. Can any one please help.

Dinesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add items to an NSMutableDictionary simply call

```
[myDictionary setObject:someObject forKey:@"objectName"];
```

Comment: If have 3 user how to add. for the first user I call [my dict set obj:'abc' forKey:@"Name"]; so it will be in the dictionary. If want to add another user name 'xyz'to the same dictionary How do I add it. I kind of have problem understand dictionaries. Could please explain briefly.

Comment: You cannot put multiple entries in the dictionary with the same key, instead you should consider an array of dictionaries or a dictionary with arrays as objects, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You either add all of your information at one time to a new NSDictionary or use an NSMutableDictionary to add as you go.